# Getstream firebase auth react native documentation?

Tags: firebase, react-native, getstream-io, getstream-chat

Not sure if anyone has any experience with getstream and react native.

I followed there tutorial to implement getstreams SDK into my existing app and its working great but I'm stuck on tokens. I've successfully set up firebase so when a new user signs up I can see there UID and information over on both firebase auth and getstream but I'm hung up on my frontend getting the user to sign in on the chat with there token. I set up firebase with there extension but still having issues. Works great with dev.tokens but just can't get past this part. Is there any examples out there or better documentation for this? Thank you!

Only documentation I can find.. not specific to react native
https://getstream.io/chat/docs/react/tokens_and_authentication/

This is currently how I initialize my user.. the user token is hard coded in my chat config file.

```
// useChatClient.js

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StreamChat } from 'stream-chat';
import { chatApiKey, chatUserId, chatUserName, chatUserToken } from './chatConfig';

const user = {
  id: chatUserId,
  name: chatUserName,
};

const chatClient = StreamChat.getInstance(chatApiKey);

export const useChatClient = () => {
  const [clientIsReady, setClientIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setupClient = async () => {
      try {
        chatClient.connectUser(user, chatUserToken);
        setClientIsReady(true);

        // connectUser is an async function. So you can choose to await for it or not depending on your use case (e.g. to show custom loading indicator)
        // But in case you need the chat to load from offline storage first then you should render chat components
        // immediately after calling `connectUser()`.
        // BUT ITS NECESSARY TO CALL connectUser FIRST IN ANY CASE.
      } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
          console.error(`An error occurred while connecting the user: ${error.message}`);
        }
      }
    };

    // If the chat client has a value in the field `userID`, a user is already connected
    // and we can skip trying to connect the user again.
    if (!chatClient.userID) {
      setupClient();
    }
  }, []);

  return {
    clientIsReady,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to request the token from the Firebase cloud function (`ext-auth-chat-getStreamUserToken`), and then initialise the current user with that token.

There is a guide and video showing how to do this using the Stream Chat Flutter SDK:

- https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/token_generation_with_firebase/
- https://youtu.be/Dt_taxX98sg

Comment: Thanks! do you know of any react native docs for this? Unfortunately I'm not using flutter.